# Jquery Select load back after refresh page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Well, It's a simple one and I know there are a lot of source about this thing.
I've a jquery script like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetStateList","Controllers1")", { sOId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.PersonnelNumber + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>

public JsonResult GetStateList(string sOId)
    {
        string sPositionNumber = Session["xPersonnelNumber"].ToString();

        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        List<Employee> StateList = db.Employees.Where(x => x.OrganizationNumber == sOId && x.Name != null).OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
        return Json(StateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

After the page refresh, the `StateId` option is empty. How can I keep the option list after the page is refresh? If I remove the `.Empty()`, it will append another option. It's cascading dropdown using MVC .NET

Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in your country options it is been selected first option automatically while you refresh,
so you can set your desire country for the states in page loading.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        **$('#CountryId').val('desire country');**

        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("@Url.Action("GetStateList","Controllers1")", { sOId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#StateId").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#StateId").append("<option value='" + row.PersonnelNumber + "'>" + row.Name + "</option>")
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless. There are however ways to persist data in ASP.NET MVC:

- Hidden Field
- Cookies
- Query String
- ViewData
- ViewBag
- TempData

Good article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/state-management-in-asp-net-mvc

However most of these methods require you to post the data to the controller, and as such data will get lost on refresh.

So viable options are...

**Option 1**: Caching

You could use a simple [memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) to store the list against a custom identifier, such as the user ID for a period of time, and update it every time the GetStateList method is called. Populating the initial list on page load from the cache.

**Option 2**: Browser side persistence

You could look at browser side persistence of data and look into things like:

- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)
- [Web storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)
- [PouchDb](https://pouchdb.com/)
- [Browser Cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)